# Authentication error when setting up Jenkins to talk to git

Tags: git, http, ssh, jenkins

I am trying to setup Jenkins on windows that would talk to a remote Android git repository. I However, keep getting the following error:

```
Using strategy: Default
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/***********`enter code here`
git --version
git version 1.7.4.msysgit.0.173.g83185.dirty
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone https://github.com/*********
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone https://github.com/*************
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.clone(CliGitAPIImpl.java:219)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1001)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:942)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:942)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1101)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1364)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:670)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:575)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\PortableGit-pre-alpha-64-bit\cmd\git.cmd clone --progress -o origin https://github.com/******************* <http://localhost:8080/job/*********%20SCM%20Change%20Build%20-%20JenkinsTest2/ws/"> returned status code 128:
stdout: Cloning into <http://localhost:8080/job/******%20Change%20Build%20-%20JenkinsTest2/ws/...>

stderr: fatal: Authentication failed

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:773)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.clone(CliGitAPIImpl.java:217)
    ... 14 more
Trying next repository
ERROR: Could not clone repository
FATAL: Could not clone
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1013)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:942)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:942)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1101)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1364)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:670)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:575)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
```

I tried to setup ssh keys using:

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

However when I get to the step:

> ssh -T git@github.com

I get the following error:

> Permission denied (public key)
>
> enter code here

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and if I even need to setup the ssh keys, given that I am trying to use the https url

would appreciate any pointer

Comment: Did you upload your ssh public key to github?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem because I was using the https URL instead of the ssh url in Jenkins. Once I changed the url in the repository section, it worked as advertised.